# Multiplos submits chamando multiplos métodos em um único formulário

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Olá! Tenho um formulário que contém dois botões, cada botão, ao clicar, me leva a um método diferente dentro de um mesmo controller. Como fazer para o que preciso ser realizado? Pois não estou conseguindo.

formulário

```
<%= form_tag (@portabilidade), method: :get, id: "form-motivo" do %>   <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Motivo</strong>
    <%= text_area_tag :motivo, @portabilidade.motivo, class: 'form-control' %>   </div>   <%= button_tag "Liberar", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "btn-liberar" %>   <%= button_tag "Reter", class: "btn btn-info", id: "btn-reter" %> <% end %>
```

Javascript

```
  $("#btn-reter").on("click", function () {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#form-motivo').attr('action', "/reter");
      $("#form-motivo").submit();
  });

  $("#btn-liberar").on("click", function () {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#form-motivo').attr('action', "/liberar");
      $("#form-motivo").submit();
  });
```

Não recebo erro nenhum, apenas a URL muda e não grava, nem entra em nenhum dos métodos.

A minha URL que era pra ser assim:

```
/portabilidades/:id/reter ou .../liberar
```

Ficou assim e não funcionou:

```
portabilidades/61?utf8=✓&motivo=erer&button=
```

Onde está meu erro? Agradeço!

Comment: já tentou trocar o :get por :post ?

Comment: Sim, fiz varias trocas, porém nada surtiu efeito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o `formaction`

```
<button type="submit" formaction="/reter">Reter</button>
<button type="submit" formaction="/liberar">Liberar</button>
```

Aqui funcionou excepcionalmente :D